# Google Chrome extension - background script not loading unless served from my local machine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've build my extension, all works great when run locally in develop mode... but when I upload it and install from the web store, my background script **background/background.min.js** doesn't load. Actually, I can see in the inspector that it is requested, with a 200 response code but the contents of the response is empty.

Is there something wrong with my code?

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "X",
"version": "0.0.7",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "X",
"author": "X",
"icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
},
"default_locale": "en",
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "storage",
    "https://www.x.com/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "https://www.x.com/*"
        ],
        "css": [
            "css/x.min.css"
        ]
    },
    {
        "matches": [
            "https://www.x.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/jquery.min.js",
            "js/www-widgetapi.js",
            "js/jquery.debounce.js",
            "js/x.min.js"
        ]
    }
],
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background/background.min.js"
    ]
},
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "background/*.js",
    "icons/*.png",
    "images/*.svg",
    "images/*.jpg",
    "font/*.eot",
    "font/*.svg",
    "font/*.ttf",
    "font/*.woff",
    "font/*.woff2",
    "templates/*.html"
],
"key": "x",
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "x.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: why two matches in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the source map from the file and also added a `default_icon` and `browser_action` to manifest.json. One of these fixed the issue, I suspect the former.